# Ajax / Jquery and window.open trigger pop-up blocker in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have been trying to use ajax and jquery as an alternative to window.open to avoid the pop-up blocker, with no success.

Some of the alternatives I have tried are:

1)

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "list.aspx",
data: jsonData,
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
success: function(msg) {
    window.open("edit_page.aspx"); 
},
error: function(msg) {
    alert("error");
}
});
```

2)

```
var url = 'page.aspx';

var $a = $('<a>', {
    href: url,
    target: '_blank'
});

$(document.body).append($a);

$a.click();
```

Finally, modal dialog as bootstrap as an alternative is not allowing me to load an aspx page.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Honestly, it's tricky. If you trigger an any tab or popup without the clients direct action, it's usually flagged. I use this to open a page:

Try this:

Call `window.open` before calling $.ajax and save it:

```
var openwindow=window.open(PATH);
```

On callback set location property of the saved window reference:

```
openwindow.location=url;
```

---

You can also try to make your own popup.

For example:

```
<style>
 #popup{display:none;}
</style>
<div id='popup'></div>
```

And you jquery you can populate your popup and display it.

```
success: function(msg){
 $('#popup').load('edit_page.aspx');
 $('#popup').show();
},
```

And then you can style it and position #popup. Also add a close button. Would that work for you?

Comment: Hi Matt, thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. I tried, but still got the pop-up blocker..

Comment: Can you create your own popup and not use the browser functions? For example, hide or show a hidden div as a popup alternative.

Comment: I added a different solution above. Let me know if its a good idea for you.

Comment: While your solution work, unfortunately even if I locate the div in different areas of the screen, it makes the edition difficult for the end user. The popup opens an editor, which enables the user to provide comments. The button that opens the popup is located next to every single record shown in a screen. Therefore, as the user scroll down, even if the div is located on a side of the screen, it does not provide an user friendly interface. Good idea thought!

Answer (score 0):

I had to ended up using Bootstrap dialog, and iframe to load the aspx page.